# Savlon & Dettol as surface disinfectant from COVID-19

Tags: covid-19, disinfection

Can Savlon be used as surface disinfectant from SARS-CoV-2 virus? It is being said that Dettol was tested as disinfectant for previous coronaviruses, so probably it will also work well against SARS-CoV-2. But I have not found any information regarding Savlon. Main active ingredient of Savlon is cetrimide and chlorhexidine digluconate.

Comment: Soap and water work better.

Comment: Using Savlon or Dettol is convinient to use than soap and water.

Answer (score 1):

The EPA has a database that you can search for tested effectiveness against SARS-CoV-2 virus.  You need to find the EPA registration number of the product you have and check it against their database.

Dettol products containing a high concentration of alcohol are thought to be effective as a surface disinfectant ( greater than 70% ethanol/propylalcohol ).

> Specific Dettol products have demonstrated effectiveness (>99.9% inactivation) against coronavirus strains from the same family as the 2019 Novel Coronavirus (COVID-19) in third party laboratory testing, when used in accordance with the directions for use.  These products are: Dettol Antibacterial Surface Cleanser Spray, Dettol Antibacterial Surface Cleanser Wipes, Dettol All-In-One Disinfectant Spray, and Dettol Disinfectant Liquid.
>
> Given the structural similarities of the COVID-19 virus to the coronavirus strains tested previously (SARS-CoV, MERS-CoV, Human Coronavirus), and based on the evidence available to us, we would expect our Dettol products (listed above) to be effective against the new strain. Definitive scientific confirmation of this, as with all other commercially available virucides, can only be provided once testing against COVID-19 Coronavirus has been conducted, following release of the strain by relevant health authorities.

https://www.epa.gov/pesticide-registration/list-n-disinfectants-use-against-sars-cov-2

https://www.dettol.co.uk/about-us/understanding-coronavirus/